# How to determine if a user is in a security group?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I am using the code below to get the user groups but I am not sure how to code it to say that if the user is in "TestGroup" do something if not redirect the page?

```
   Dim resEnt As SearchResult
        Try
            For Each resEnt In mySearcher.FindAll()
                LabelUser.Text = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties.Item("DisplayName").Value
                LabelLocation.Text = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties.Item("SystemUserLocation").Value
                LabelState.Text = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties.Item("st").Value
                LabelCountry.Text = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties.Item("c").Value

                Dim result As SearchResult = mySearcher.FindOne()
                If (result Is Nothing) Then
                Else

                    Dim groupColl As Object
                    For Each groupColl In resEnt.Properties("memberof")
                        Dim GroupArray As Array = groupColl.split(",")
                        Select Case GroupArray(0).replace("CN=", "")
                            Case "TestGroup"
                                'Continue loading page
                            Case Else
                                'Prevent page from loading????

                        End Select


                    Next groupColl
                End If
            Next
        Catch f As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(f.ToString)
        End Try
```

Comment: There is a method in asp.net IsUserInRole ? do you try this

Comment: can you show me an example? I am new to this